Could the current agreement with Topps/Fanatics and the MLB be considered a monopoly on baseball cards?
Back in 2021, the MLB struck a deal with Fanatics to be the sole, exclusive licensee for MLB baseball cards once the agreements with Topps and Panini expired at the end of 2022. Then in early 2022, Topps was purchased by Fanatics.
Relatedly, back in the 80s, Topps and the MLBPA were sued by Fleer to open up the market since Topps had an exclusive agreement with the MLBPA/MLB. After several years of litigation, the court ordered the union to offer group licenses for baseball cards to companies other than Topps. Fleer and another company, Donruss, were thus allowed to begin making cards in 1981.
Could the current situation with Topps/Fanatics be considered a monopoly, much in the same way it was back in the 80s? And if not, why?

@Barmar Do you mean “so what” in the sense that it’s no longer politically/regulatorily relevant that a monopoly exists?
